# insert string on simple html dom output

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I need to insert a string into the dom elements so that they display when `simple_html_dom::__tostring` is called, but so they do not affect the simple_html_dom api.

So, if I have a simple_html_dom node where `$node->outertext` is the following:

```
<div class="MyClass">
    <div itemprop="myVar">

    </div>
</div>
```

Then, I want to assign `$string='INSERTED STRING'` to auto-insert on display. The output would be like:

```
<div class="MyClass">
    INSERTED STRING
    <div itemprop="myVar">

    </div>
</div>
```

So the idea is that when interacting with the elements using the simple_html_dom api, its as if `$string` were not inserted. Then when the html is output, insert `$string` immediately after(or before) the opening (or closing) tag.

For example, `$node->innertext = $string.$node->innertext` is not acceptable because it affects the parsing since `$node` would have a new child at the beginning.

Is there a built-in way to do that?
If not, would there be a way to accomplish it without editing the source of `simple_html_dom`?

**EDIT:** Performance is not a concern because the output will be cached.
  **AND:** I just realized I could just do `$node->setAttribute('insertOnDisplay',$string)` then scrape the document again before displaying, remove the attribute, and put the attribute value to the innertext. I'll see if I get other better options (and test it out) before posting it as an answer.

Comment: I'm confused why you can't just insert the text right before you'd print out the html?

Comment: if its just for output purposes then just create another variable if you want the original node untouched

Comment: I'm scraping a document and when certain conditions are met (say a node has a certain tag or attribute), then I pass the elements to other functions to act on them, say add a `value` attribute or... any of these functions can append text that should not be seen by `simple_html_dom` (except when outputting). Because of this, either of your approaches would add significant complication I think...

Comment: Though, I now realize, I could just do `$node->setAttribute('insertOnDisplay',$string)` then scrape the document again before displaying, remove the attribute, and put the attribute value to the innertext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I extended simple_html_dom and `simple_html_dom_node` and in `simple_html_dom_node`, I created a `prepareOutput` method that goes through and finds any attributes with `jdom-[before|after]:[outertext|innertext]` then set the text to be before or after `innertext` or `outertext`. It feels like a hacky way to do it, but it works.

I also changed `simple_html_dom` a little bit to use `new static::$domClass` for instantiating a dom and `new static::$nodeClass` for instantiating a node instead of using `new static`, so that I could make it instantiate my subclass when creating a new node internally